# Introduction to Apache Mahout K-means clustering

Tags: java, apache, mahout, k-means

I am trying to cluster a sparse matrix with using K-means algorithm. I will use Apache mahout but I did not find any example about how can it be implement with Java. Is there any tutorial or function javadoc about it?

I have tried KmeansDriver's run() function but I did not give true parameters. Trustly, I did not understand implementation of this function. Is there a clear example about that which takes a matrix, dataset or file and gives clustered data?

Comment: Use [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) it is a much better library for any data mining task.

Comment: Weka is not working properly with very big dataset. I used it but get any result in 9 hours.

Comment: How many instances and how many clusters?

Comment: Dataset includes about 94000 sparse instances. And number of clusters can be about 1000, lower or higher. I did not determine a certain number for clusters.

Comment: Okay agreed if you have sparse instances the Weka knows how to really stretch it. Sorry though I can't help you with Mahout as I haven't used it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using KMeansDriver and explaining a bit more the parameters of its run method: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/mahout/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/clustering/syntheticcontrol/kmeans/Job.java?view=markup

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated version of the Hello World clustering example from the book 'Mahout in Action'. The example uses the Mahout version 0.9.
http://develop.nydi.ch/2014/04/02/mahout-clustering-example/

Comment: Strange, I have Mahout 0.9 and it doesn't compile.